# Loading txt file content to editable div / textarea and saving

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a simple handbook for usage in my work using bootstrap, a page will be run locally as security policies in my company and does not allow to host any servers on employee computers.

Is there a way to load the content of txt file to `div` `(contenteditable="true")` or `textarea` and save it when necessary by using `JavaScript`? I want it to work like the local version on pastebin to keep notes.

I have tried with loading content for now and failed with:

```
<html> 
    <head>
       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <textarea class="textbox" id="Brief" readonly></textarea>
       <script> $( "#Brief" ).load( "text.txt" ); </script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

The txt file would be created already, all I need is to load its content when page is opened and have possibility to save it when closing page.

Comment: JavaScript is not allowed to read the content of http files. You need a server to post the content via ajax and then save it.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I was kinda expecting that, will try to use php emulator to work with this [link](https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop)